# How can I stop all docker containers from a remote ssh command?

Tags: command-line, ssh, docker, aws

I want to kill all containers from a remote machine through a ssh command.
My current approach:

```
ssh user@website "docker kill $(docker ps -q)"
```

This is not working because `$(docker ps -q)` seems not to be working on a remote ssh code execution (While there is no problem if I have a ssh shell).

The host machine is a EC2 (AWS) with Amazon Linux.

Comment: Exactly the same problem - quoting. Use single quotes if you want `$(docker ps -q)` to be evaluated on the remote system.

Comment: Thanks, `ssh user@website 'docker kill $(docker ps -q)'` is the solution.